# flextable: align ONLY header row to center

Tags: r, alignment, flextable, header-row

I have the following code which results in below fig.
However I want the `header_row` to align center over the cols.(passed as arg.:`colwidths`, I've been searching, consulted the manual (but I'm new to R so my understanding is bad), but I'm at a lost. Everything else in the table should have the alignment it has.

```
ft <- flextable(df_BAS_sum)
ft <- set_caption(ft, caption =sprintf("Tabell 1. Arbetsmarknadsdata och nyckeltal för olika geografier, 20-64 år - %s %s", month, yr), align_with_table = F)
ft <- add_header_row(ft, colwidths = c(1,2,4,3), values = c("","Arbetskraften","Ej i arbetskraften","Nyckeltal"))
ft <- colformat_num(x = ft,
                    big.mark=" ", decimal.mark = ",",
                    na_str = "N/A")
ft <- theme_vanilla(ft)
ft
```

[image]

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: `ft <- align(ft, align = "center", part = "header")` does not do what you need?

Comment: That also align the second row (which must be a part of the 'header') with e.g. "Geografi" onwards - I ideally does not want to change that 2nd rows alignment from left to center, only top (first) row.

Comment: I think you can specify individual header rows like `ft <- align(ft, i = 1, j = NULL, align = "center", part = "header")` - change the `i=` to select rows.  Details here: https://rdrr.io/cran/flextable/man/align.html

Comment: Wow that worked! I thought I tried that before, but must have missed something, anyways thanks mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ft <- align(ft, i = 1, j = NULL, align = "center", part = "header")
```

`part = "header"` restricts it to the header rows only
`i = 1` (first row)
`j = NULL` (all columns) should avoid the undesirable realignment of the other header row.